# Unexpected inconsistency error on Fedora Core 16

Tags: fedora, fsck

I am a PhD student and I inherited a small server cluster which runs Fedora Core 16. Unfortunately, my background is in electronics and my knowledge of OS is quite limited. We just use this server to run our programs. Some of the machines fail to boot up and show this error message: [image: Picture of error message]

It seems to be a file system error. But I tried to move the HDD from a working system and it still produces the same issue. I also tried moving this HDD to a working system and that works too.

All the results I see online for this error say to repair the local disk such as /sda/ etc. But I'm not sure what `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root` is and how I can do the same here.

EDIT: As Vojtech Trefny suggested, I tried running e2fsck on the indicated disk. It said it fixed some errors, but then got stuck a little later on another screen, shown here.

[image: Picture of 2nd error message]

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem on `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root` (Fedora uses [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29), this is your root logical volume) is corrupted, you need to fix it by running `e2fsck /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root`, `e2fsck` is interactive and it will guide you through the repair.

Btw. your system is outdated, support for Fedora 16 [ended in 2013](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life), you should really migrate to a newer version.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a try. Yes, I've been wanting to update but so many people are using it they won't let me. So I'm installing it on another blade and hoping to migrate people over first and then decommission these old systems.

Comment: I tried running e2fsck as you suggested but I'm now stuck on a new error. I posted a screenshot of it in the original post above. Do you have any thoughts on what might be the cause of this error?